# NoReverseMatch Error but couldn't find its source

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am relatively new to Django and started to create my first To-Do-List.
However I get an error whenever I try to create an href that says: NoReverseMatch at /aufgabenzettel/

I have desperately tried to fix it for the last five hours and am very frustrated because the error just seems to be caused by a single line of code... Please help! It would be awesome and I really appreciate every hint!

Here's the code:

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<int:aufgabenzettel_id>", views.details, name="details")
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Aufgabenzettel

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/index.html", {
        "Aufgabenliste":Aufgabenzettel.objects.all()
    })

def details(request, aufgabenzettel_id):
    aufgabenzettel = Aufgabenzettel.objects.get(pk=aufgabenzettel_id)
    return render(request, "aufgabenzettel/details.html", {
        "details":aufgabenzettel
    })
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Aufgabenzettel(models.Model):
    Aufgabeselbst = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Aufgabeselbst}"
```

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>Aufgabenzettel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>

</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Meine Aufgaben</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for Aufgabeselbst in Aufgabenliste %}
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'details' aufgabenzettel.id %}"> 
                    Aufgabe {{ Aufgabeselbst }}
                </a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**details.html**

```
{% extends "aufgabenzettel/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h1> Aufgabe {{ details }}</h1>
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Zurück zu Aufgabe</a>
{% endblock %}
```

The exact error:

*Reverse for 'details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['aufgabenzettel/(?P<aufgabenzettel_id>[0-9]+)$']*

Whenever I delete the line `<a href="{% url 'details' aufgabenzettel.id %}">` in **index.html** the programme works perfectly fine...

Let me know if you need some more information!!

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: You loop variable is `Aufgabeselbst` and you hence likely want to write `{% url 'details' Aufgabeselbst.id %}` (Not `aufgabenzettel.id` since there is no `aufgabenzettel` in the context)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you very much Abdul! Your solution solved the problem! I once tried it with {% url 'details' aufgabeselbst.id %} but I didn't capitalize aufgabeselbst.id to Aufgabeselbst.id. You saved my day! Is there any chance to stay in touch with you in case I further need your help? Best wishes!

Comment: Glad to be of help. ;) As for staying in touch, you can ask a question on SO any day and I am quite sure someone will help (of course you need to make sure your question is clear and on-topic for Stack Overflow).